# The easiest and most efficient way to read local images in Flex 4/Air

Tags: apache-flex, image, file, flex4, air

I just wonder what you would suggest me to read an image file from the local directory in my Air application if I only have the native path (eg C:\myImage.jpg) of this image?

Since my grid item renderer needs to read those thumbnail images, the performance is very important for me. I do it with stream now but I m not sure if it is the best way. Any suggestion is highly appreciated.

Comment: You're going to need to give more information than that.

Answer (score 1):

It is not really clear for me how your application will work but here are two tips for you that I hope will help you somehow:

1. If you want to have image resources in you Flex/Air app - include them in you applications.
2. If you want to access local files (only Air app can do it) - read them as binary files - this is fastest way, because you will use lowest-file-access API available in Air.

p.s. Think about pre-populating resources for your item-renderer. Maybe some kind of caching proxy will work for you. Of course you will have to implement it. I didn't see ready to go solutions yet because it is very specific task which is not really hard to implement.

Comment: I agree with point 1, but point 2 is wrong.  You can use `FileReference.browse()` to let the user choose which file to load/show from any Flex app.